# How to design the list example as seen in Material Design Guidelines?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm learning Android programming and I'm trying to exactly reproduce the layout of a particular list item example of the [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-specs) but I'm not sure how doing it:
[image: Example]

Can you give me some help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1- In you drawables add a new xml file and name it "circle_avatar.xml"**

and insert the following code :

```
<shape 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
       android:radius="100dip"/>
   <solid
       android:color="#ff4CAF50" />
   <stroke
       android:width="2dip"
       android:color="#FFF" />
   <padding
       android:left="6dip"
       android:right="6dip"
       android:top="5dip"
       android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

**2- In your main xml layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_circle_avatar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_avatar">

                <ImageView
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:id="@+id/circle_pic"
                      android:src="@drawable/icon1"/>
   </FrameLayout>
```

**PS.** You can always make changes to that to fit your needs